# What is the meaning of the x-axis in a discrete probability and continuous probability distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Does the x-axis for both the discrete and continuous probability distribution represent the **mutually exclusive outcomes of a random trial**?
I know that for a discrete probability distribution, the y-axis is the probability, and for a continuous probability distribution the y-axis is the probability of each event happening.

Comment: *"for a continuous probability distribution the y-axis is the probability of each event happening"* is not correct as such.  You may be showing the probability density of a continuous distribution or the probability mass function of a continuous distribution or the cumulative distribution function of either type distribution (or a mixture)

Comment: @Henry, yes I made a mistake. For a continuous probability distribution the y-axis should be the probability density. But what is the meaning of the x-axis in both probability distributions?

Comment: The $x-$ axis represents the possible outcomes of the random variable.

Comment: @Matthew Holder Does that also apply for a continuous probability distribution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, and no problem!